# Cabal + Stack: specifying the packages version in the cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Normally when adding a new dependency to a `.cabal` file I specify the version of the new library I'm depending on. However `stack` works with a curated set of libraries, and I'm wondering whether it makes sense to specify the package versions in the `.cabal` file. My guess would be that specifying the `lts` version in the `stack.yaml` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether it makes sense to specify the package versions in the .cabal file.

That depends completely upon you. If you specify a package version
which is not in that particular stackage resolver, then Stack will
throw an error saying you to adjust the versioning.

> My guess would be that specifying the lts version in the stack.yaml is enough.

For private packages, it doesn't matter and I prefer not putting any version bounds there. But if it's something I ultimately plan to publish on Hackage, I usually use a [CI system like Travis](https://github.com/psibi/fb/blob/master/.travis.yml) and get the bounds right for it with some testing. In fact, I think the Stack guide recommends something like that.

Comment: I'm reviewing this after almost a year, and indeed. Upper and lower bounds in `cabal` (or `hpack`?) files are needed when publishing a package to hackage the PVP requires upper and lower bounds for every dependency of the package one is trying to publish.

Comment: @DamianNadales No, it's not needed. The stance on PVP is controversial with different opinions among different peoples.

Comment: But the [instructions on how to upload a package to hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/upload) refer to the PVP saying that "all packages should follow Haskell's Package Versioning Policy (PVP)". Does that mean that package authors don't necessarily follow the instructions on that page?

Comment: I get why you are getting confused, many people have. It is "should" in the RFC sense which translates to "recommended but not required". See this reddit discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7yfdei/haskell_ecosystem_requests/dug9f58/
But yeah, IMO it's just stupid and that sentence should be much more clearer than the current one.

Comment: CC: @DamianNadales